# How to change the privileges to other host in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a MySQL user called `myname`. I configured in `.conf` file for my project to point to host `db`: `jdbc:mysql://db/db_name`(when project run it check the configuration in this file to find path to db). However, the project show me the error: `Unknown database 'db_name'`(when execute). Then I login to mysql with user `myname` and check the grants and see that:

```
    +-----------------------------------------------------+
    | Grants for myname@%                                 |
    +-----------------------------------------------------+
    | GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myname'@'%'                  |
    | GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name`.* TO 'myname'@'%' |
    +-----------------------------------------------------+
```

- I supposed that the host should be `myname@db` not `myname@%`, then I can query to `db_name` without error. If my thought like this is correct, how can I change the privileges to `myname@db`?
- If not, what can I do to solve the error: `Unknown database 'db_name'`?

Comment: Show the code that attempt to make the connection

Comment: if you log into your database via command line or a db client as 'myname' then you should see that db_name. This would confirm there is nothing wrong with your privileges. Them grant commands look ok to me.

Comment: the `%` is the hostname, in this case it means something like any-ip and it has nothing to do with the database name, it could be ex, `'myname'@'192.168.20.22'`

Comment: run a `show databases` and verify that a database named db_name is present

Comment: @MadDokMike I used `show databases` and only see `information_schema` database(with `myname` user). However, I can see `db_name` in phpMyadmin.

Comment: try the following -----------------------
CREATE DATABASE `db_name2`;

CREATE USER 'myname2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'supersecure';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myname2'@'%';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name2`.* TO 'myname2'@'%' ;--------------------------ok so that didnt format in stack as clear as i had hoped. I have just ran them commands on my local db and can log in as myname2 and see the database.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i'll answer instead of comment, for the purposes of the pasted code being readable. I have run the following test scenario modelling your problem and it works for me. Does your db_name database exist ?

CREATE DATABASE `db_name2`;

CREATE USER 'myname2'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'supersecure';

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myname2'@'%';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `db_name2`.* TO 'myname2'@'%' ;